# Handle nil value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, null

`NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)` returns nil. (correct) If the value is `nil` I need to set variable `stringResponse` to `""` else  to what `NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)` returns. I am doing it this way:

```
override func start() {
    if self.cancelled {
        return
    }

    var stringResponse: String?
    var urlString: String!
    if self.arduinoConnection.arduinoHTTPPort == 80 {
        urlString = String(format: "http://%@/arduino/%@/%i/", arguments: [self.arduinoConnection.arduinoAddress, self.arduinoConnection.pinType.lowercaseString, self.arduinoConnection.arduinoPin])
    } else {
        urlString = String(format: "http://%@:%i/arduino/%@/%i/", arguments: [self.arduinoConnection.arduinoAddress, self.arduinoConnection.arduinoHTTPPort, self.arduinoConnection.pinType.lowercaseString, self.arduinoConnection.arduinoPin])
    }
    //let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://10.0.3.9:8888/index.html")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    if self.cancelled {
        return
    }


    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in

        stringResponse = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String ?? ""

        if (stringResponse == "") {
            self.arduinoConnection.state = .Failed
            self.arduinoConnection.switchState = false
            self.arduinoConnection.statusText = "Failed To Connect"

            self.delegate?.didFinishDownloading(GettingState.Failed, statusText: "Failed To Connect", switchState: false)
        } else {
            self.arduinoConnection.state = .Downloaded
            if (stringResponse == "0") {
                self.arduinoConnection.state = .Downloaded
                self.arduinoConnection.switchState = false
                self.ardCTS.state = .Downloaded
                self.ardCTS.switchState = false
                self.arduinoConnection.statusText = "Connected"

                self.delegate?.didFinishDownloading(GettingState.Downloaded, statusText: "Connected", switchState: false)
            } else if (stringResponse == "1") {
                self.arduinoConnection.state = .Downloaded
                self.arduinoConnection.switchState = true
                self.arduinoConnection.statusText = "Connected"
                self.ardCTS.state = .Downloaded
                self.ardCTS.switchState = true

                self.delegate?.didFinishDownloading(GettingState.Downloaded, statusText: "Connected", switchState: true)
            }
        }
        self.executing = false
        self.finished = true
    }
    executing = true
    self.finished = false
}
```

When app runs this code I have:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Help me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var stringResponse: String?

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request,
                         queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in

    stringResponse = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String ?? ""
```

You're not testing for errors. You may be passed a `nil` NSData because this interface hasn't been fully audited yet by Apple, and still passes implicitly unwrapped optionals. You have to deal with those.

```
if let error = error {
    // We got an error; do something about it
    return
}

// OK, now we know that the data is good
stringResponse = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

You shouldn't cast this as anything. This function returns a `String?`, which is what `stringResponse` is.

Comment: This line replaces your entire if/else block. If you're getting a runtime error, then the cause is elsewhere (perhaps `data` is an `NSData!`). You need to look at the crash report to see the exact line that is failing.

Comment: this is `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest`

Comment: You're not checking `error` are you? The connection probably failed and `data` is probably nil.

Comment: It is nil. But how to do that if block

Comment: Post your actual code; how are you making this call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78461/discussion-between-nikita-zernov-and-rob-napier).